# Find the smallest number among three numbers using if

Tags: java, if-statement, int, java.util.scanner

So i'm a confused  what is in those if brackets, the code works fine but i don't understand it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);    
    int a = scanner.nextInt(); 
    int b = scanner.nextInt();
    int c = scanner.nextInt();
    if(b < a) {
      a = b; //This part is confusing to me
    }
    if(c < a) {
      c = a; 
    }    
    System.out.println("Smallest number is " + a);
}
```

Comment: That line is just a regular assignment. What about it is confusing you?

Comment: @resueman I think the fact that the assignment is happening at that particular location is confusing them. It is confusing from a readability standpoint, really.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't accuse this approach of being clear or expressive.  "Clever" comes to mind and "clever" code, while fun to write, is very often difficult to support.  But for such a small program, consider this an opportunity to step through the logic one line at a time with a variety of inputs.  Come up with several sets of test inputs and walk through the logic.  What does it do?  Do you then see why it does it?

Comment: Even worse than "clever", it's also wrong.  If `c` is the smallest initial value, it'll output the smaller of `a` and `b`.

Comment: Good catch @azurefrog . There is totally a bug on the `c = a;` line.

Answer (score 2):

`a` is being used for two purposes:

1. It is storing the first input.
2. It is then being updated with a new value (from other variables, that got their value from input,) if that new value is smaller.

If I were writing the program, I wouldn't have designated both of these responsibilities to `a`, but that is what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the logic slightly but you can apply the same method to your case.

```
For a, b, and c.

If a > b
   a = b; // now a < b
otherwise leave a alone.
```

1. At this point, a is always less that b

```
if a > c
   a = c // now a < c
otherwise, leave a alone.
```

2. At this point, a is always less than c.

Because of 1. and 2. `a` is less than both `b` and `c`.